# How do I set value of this json response to a php variable?

Tags: php, json

How do I set the value of "id" to a PHP variable?

My response:

```
{"success":1,"error":[],"data":{"id":68}}
```

I tried:

```
$id = $response->return->id;
```

But I received this error.

> Error:  PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: You need to look up `json_decode` you're working with a json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your JSON is still a string?

```
{"success":1,"error":[],"data":{"id":68}}
```

Have you decoded the JSON so you can access it as an array?

```
$myJSONString = '{"success":1,"error":[],"data":{"id":68}}' ;
$a = json_decode($myJSONString,true) ;
```

Once you have it in an array you can access the elements

```
// read it
$myID = $a['data']['id'] ;

// set it
$a['data']['id'] = 100 ;
```